# Looping in iMacros

Tags: imacros

I need to download a report from a website. On this website, my download request will routinely time out several times before success. Instead of manually re-trying the download until it succeeds, I wrote a simple, stupid iMacros script to automate:

```
VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Download
WAIT SECONDS=10
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Download
WAIT SECONDS=10
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Download
'(repeats steps 10 more times)
```

I would like to improve upon this by using the proper looping code to repeat the download request, and to also cease looping after successful download.

Answer (score 1):

```
VERSION BUILD=8961227 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !ERRORIGNORE YES
ONDOWNLOAD FOLDER=* FILE=+_{{!NOW:yyyymmdd_hhnnss}} WAIT=YES
TAG POS=2 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=TXT:Download
WAIT SECONDS=10
```

Did u try using this button. http://prntscr.com/acu3fb

Comment: This works when running from the interface, but I'd like to save the macro as a bookmark and run it from there. Is there no way to specify a loop within the code itself? Also this method will still continue looping after successful download.